# Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON JavaScriptSerializer.

Tags: c#, json

I keep getting this error when trying to create json.  This is the full error

```
Error during serialization or deserialization using the JSON 
JavaScriptSerializer. The length of the string exceeds
the value set on the maxJsonLength property.
```

My code is as follows

```
public ActionResult ChangeRequests_Read([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var data = GetRequests();
        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var result = new ContentResult();
        serializer.MaxJsonLength = Int32.MaxValue; // Whatever max length you want here
        result.Content = serializer.Serialize(data.ToDataSourceResult(request));
        result.ContentType = "application/json";
        return result;

        //return Json(GetRequests().ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

and this pulls from here

```
public static IEnumerable<ChangeRequestsVM> GetRequests()
    {
        var model = CompanyContextFactory.GetContextPerRequest();
        var chrwVM =  model.ChangeRequestsHDRs.Where(ch=> ch.CompanyID == GlobalVariables.CompanyID).Select(ch=> new ChangeRequestsVM
        {
            RequestID = ch.RequestID, 
            CompanyID = ch.CompanyID,
            ClientID = ch.ClientID,
            EmployeeID = (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ch.EmployeeID)) ? "NA" : ch.EmployeeID,
            AssignmentType = ch.AssignmentType,
            Key1 = ch.Key1,
            Key2 = ch.Key2,
            LogonID = ch.LogonID,
            ProcessDate = ch.ProcessDate,
            ProcessTime = ch.ProcessTime,
            ProcessUserID = ch.ProcessUserID,
            RequestDate = ch.RequestDate,
            RequestExport = ch.RequestExport,
            RequestNote = ch.RequestNote,
            RequestOrigin = Convert.ToChar(ch.RequestOrigin),
            RequestProcess = ch.RequestProcess,
            RequestStatus = ch.RequestStatus,
            RequestTime = ch.RequestTime,
            RequestType = Convert.ToChar(ch.RequestType),
            ResponseNote = ch.ResponseNote,
            TableName = ch.TableName,
            TransferDate = ch.TransferDate,
            TransferTime = ch.TransferTime,
            TransferUserID = ch.TransferUserID,
            dispOrigin = (Convert.ToChar(ch.RequestOrigin) == ChangeRequestOrigin.System) ? "System" : (Convert.ToChar(ch.RequestOrigin) == ChangeRequestOrigin.Client) ? "Client" : "Employee",
            dispRequestType = (Convert.ToChar(ch.RequestType) == ChangeRequestType.Insert) ? "Insert" : (Convert.ToChar(ch.RequestType) == ChangeRequestType.Alter) ? "Change" : "Delete",
            dispStatus = FieldTranslation.GetEnumDescription(typeof(enChangeRequestStatus), ch.RequestStatus ?? 0)
        }).OrderByDescending(ch=> ch.RequestID);
        return chrwVM;
    }
```

Why is my json exceeding length?  I've made it so the method only pulls one item from the database and still get the error.

Comment: Maybe one of your fields has too much data in it, like `ch.RequestNote` or `ch.ResponseNote`.

Comment: If using `JavaScriptSerializer` is not a hard requirement for you, then I'd suggest you switching over to Json.NET.

Answer (score 1):

You need to increase the size of the MaxJsonLength property:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.maxjsonlength.aspx

This is done in the configuration file. See link above for details.

**Update:**

Since you are using MVC, you can use the following app setting:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:MaxJsonDeserializerMembers" value="123456789" />
...
</appSettings>
```

However, be aware this is a potential security risk. Read more here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh975440(v=vs.120).aspx